# How to you get server information in HTTP response header for Apache Tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, httpresponse

We have n number of servers behind a load balancer. When a http request comes in, it is routed to one of the servers by round robin method. My question is, is there any way we can send the sever information in http response(The server to which the request is directed to) ?

Comment: Does the load balancer strip headers? If not, why can't you simply add a custom header entry?

Comment: Have you looked at the ServletRequest class yet?

Comment: I do not want to change the application code. Is there any possibility to do it at Tomcat level?

Comment: Why do you want this information?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the information you want (IP address? some friendly name for the server?) you can easily just set the header using response.setHeader("Backend-Machine", "ServerName").

The real question is how to get that information. Most servers have multiple NICs which means you can't just pick one randomly and return the IP address (you're liable to get 127.0.0.1 which doesn't help anyone). If this is important to you, I'd recommend setting a system property on JVM launch that includes whatever string you think identifies the server. Then, write a Filter that just adds that string to every response.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer on the sub-question "Where do you get the info".
TLDR;
say in: `/opt/tomcat-<your_version>/lib$` execute:

```
java -cp catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```

You will get something like this, which is probably what you are looking for. I would pare it down to only what you need since the format essentially is just K/Vs, one per line, with colon as the delimiter.

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.59
Server built:   Oct 6 2020 16:57:18 UTC
Server number:  8.5.59.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.4.0-72-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10
JVM Vendor:     Private Build
```

I cannot believe this is so difficult. There should be just some Tomcat property that would allow it to tack the ServerInfo to the response, most likely in the "Server" response header.

Anyhow, since I have been digging for this, I have to say

> Christopher Schultz

below is correct about the filter that needs to be added to the application. At least that would solve the problem for the given application. But how about the rest of the apps running on the same server (deployed WARs). Add a filter to each one? Sounds redundant. Here is a sample code snippet, though (you can see the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995398/how-to-set-custom-http-header-server-for-spring-boot-applications) here), many thanks to Maciej Walkowiak:

```
@Bean
public Filter myFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            res.addHeader("Server", "my very custom server");

            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    };
}
```

And for the brave, here is the source of it. You can open this class in IntelliJ `org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`, which will reveal:

[image: ServerInfo Class - loads ServerInfo.properties]
Just grab the calls that you are interested in and populate what they return in you the Server header that you create in your Spring MVC filter.
And then the ServerInfo.properties, you can see just three of them:
[image]

Personally, I set the server header like so in application.properties of my Spring Boot project:

```
server.server-header="Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]"
```

This solves the issue on a server level and I don't need to touch the code for this included - tested in FireFox Developer Tools, network tab.