# How to set custom Http header "server" for Spring Boot applications

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

By default the HTTP "server" header for Spring Boot applications with embedded Tomcat is:

```
Server → Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

How can it in **Spring Boot** be achieved to use another (custom) "server" header?

For Tomcat itself, it can be configured at the `<Connector>` element in XML via the `server` attribute:

From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/security-howto.html#Connectors :

> The server attribute controls the value of the Server HTTP header. The default value of this header for Tomcat 4.1.x to 8.0.x is Apache-Coyote/1.1. This header can provide limited information to both legitimate clients and attackers.

But attackers will still know that this is a Tomcat server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set [custom headers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-custom) using the [StaticHeadersWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/header/writers/StaticHeadersWriter.html) in your Security config, here's a Java config example:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Server","here to serve you"))
      ....
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

FYI, in the latest versions of Spring Boot you can simply set the "server.server-header" property to achieve the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can add additional headers (or overwrite existing ones) with your custom [Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) implementation. For example:

```
@Bean
public Filter myFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            res.addHeader("Server", "my very custom server");

            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use Spring Security you can use TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory and add a TomcatConnectorCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.setTomcatConnectorCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(c -> c.setProperty("Server", "Pleased to serve you")));
    return tomcat;
}
```