# How to hide the embedded tomcat version when we have errors while using springboot with microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, server, microservices, embedded-tomcat

As we have default tomcat in our springboot project, not able to set as in the below url.

https://www.inoks.com/hide-tomcat-version-from-the-error-message/
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/hide-tomcat-version-number/

Also tried by adding **server.info=Application Server** inside the application.properties.

but its not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9tui.png)

Comment: Hoeever my answer is not the answer on your questenion anyway if you are using spring-boot-starter package you don't need external servlet container you could rub it very simple, i.e. i am using gradle therefo in command line i could start app: .\gradlew.bat bootRun

Comment: can you please ell what is the versions you are using for spring boot

Comment: @silentsudo spring boot version 2.1.5

Comment: @MichaelUshakov i am not using the external container

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461804/embedded-tomcat-hardening-how-to-alter-override-advertised-server-information

Answer (score 0):

Showing java error details to the end user is not always a good idea. You may want to customize the spring boot whitelabel error page

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page